# Restful Codeigniter

Tags: php, rest, api, codeigniter

i try to use Restful Codeigniter for make Restful API, i done all installation requirements, and download all Libraries, but when i make this code

```
<?php
require APPPATH . '/libraries/REST_Controller.php';

class api extends REST_Controller{
  function __construct(){
    parent:: __construct();
  }

  function get_osama(){
    $this -> response('Hello Word');
  }
}
?>
```

, show me an error in Postman:

```html
</style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="container">
                <h1>An Error Was Encountered</h1>
                <p>Your C:\xampp\htdocs\api\application\config/rest.php file does not appear to contain a valid configuration array.</p>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

and in browser also give me this error:

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Your C:\xampp\htdocs\api\application\config/rest.php file does not appear to contain a valid configuration array.

Comment: I think the error is clear enought ? look the file and debug it.

Comment: It's because your C:\xampp\htdocs\api\application\config/rest.php file does not appear to contain a valid configuration array

Comment: Can you please post the rest.php file?

Comment: [Rest API](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/rest-api-in-codeigniter/) in Codeigniter this might help you

Comment: this file i download it from GetHub as a part of RESTful server implementation for CodeIgniter, and i don't know any thing about it?

Comment: this a rest.php file:

Comment: sorry, this file too big, i cannot paste it in comment, but i 
But I do not think the problem is in a rest file, because it's a ready-made file, loaded daily by hundreds?

Comment: The error message clearly states that the file contains invalid data.

Edit your Question to include the file or post a link to the file (upload it to some paste site like Gist, Pastenbin etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $this -> response(array('Hello Word')); instead if $this -> response('Hello Word');